# Python sorting arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, sorting, for-loop

I am given an array with names and grades and i want to sort the grades from highest to lowest and print them in the following format:

Rank   Name    Grade

I've written some code based on the array given but i'm kind of stuck now. Any help would be awesome. Thanks

```
grade = {"Nick": 90, "Josh": 80, "Jon" : 70, "David": 100, "Ed": 60, "Kelly": 50}

numerical_grades = grade.values()

ranking = sorted(numerical_grades, reverse = True)
rank=0
print ranking
print "%-8s%-10s%-2s" % ("Rank", "Name", "Grade")

for number_grade in numerical_grades:
     for name in grade:
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value

Comment: Your code doesn't have any arrays in it. Python by itself doesn't have arrays (only lists). What you have there is a dict (dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
import operator
grade = {"Nick": 90, "Josh": 80, "Jon" : 70, "David": 100, "Ed": 60, "Kelly": 50}
sorted_grades = [(rank, x[0], x[1]) for rank, x in enumerate(sorted(grade.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True), 1)]
print(sorted_grades))
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 'David', 100), (2, 'Nick', 90), (3, 'Josh', 80), (4, 'Jon', 70), (5, 'Ed', 60), (6, 'Kelly', 50)]
```

A slightly neater version (with a dictionary output) is as follows:

```
sorted_grades = dict(enumerate(sorted(grade.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True), 1))
print(sorted_grades)
```

**Output**

```
{1: ('David', 100), 2: ('Nick', 90), 3: ('Josh', 80), 4: ('Jon', 70), 5: ('Ed', 60), 6: ('Kelly', 50)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the entire dictionary and simply iterate over it afterwards:

```
>>> import operator
>>> grade = {"Nick": 90, "Josh": 80, "Jon" : 70, "David": 100, "Ed": 60, "Kelly": 50}
>>> sorted_by_grade = sorted(grade.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[::-1]
>>> list(enumerate(sorted_by_grade))
[(0, ('David', 100)), (1, ('Nick', 90)), (2, ('Josh', 80)), (3, ('Jon', 70)), (4, ('Ed', 60)), (5, ('Kelly', 50))]
```

Comment: The user wants to print `rank`, `name` and `grade`.

Comment: Why [::-1] instead of reverse=True?

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted_grades = [(grade[name], name) for name in grades]
sorted_grades.sort(reverse=True)
for n, grade in enumerate(sorted_grades):
    print(n+1, grade[1], grade[0]
```

This uses a list comprehension to create a list of tuples, `(grade, name)`. You can then use pythons sort function to sort the list highest to lowest. The print statement in the for loop produces the output you appear to desire.

Comment: Just so you know, you can enter a starting number in the `enumerate` function. you so can skip the `n+1` part.

Comment: @Exelian Never came across that. Thanks for the info.